# Using value from second table as path in mysql json_extract

Tags: mysql

I have two tables-

```
table 1
---------
id      name    value
1       abc      8276

table 2
---------
id     t1_id     value
1      1         {"8271":"a","8276":"b"}
```

And i want the result in the below format

```
Result
------
id     name      t2_value
1      abc       b
```

I tried the below query but it is showing error

```
select t2.id, t1.name, JSON_EXTRACT(t2.value, '$.t1.value') from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it, you pass `t1.value` as string, not as the actual value. Building a string from the actual value with `CONCAT()` should work.

```
select t2.id, t1.name, JSON_EXTRACT(t2.value, CONCAT('$."', t1.value, '"')) from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id;
```

- see it working live [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c38d4f7a6fc329ee4852c93285d801d9)

Comment: I tried but it is showing Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 6

Comment: @daemon There were missing some doublequotes, that's all. Added a link where you can see that it works.